# Webdriver wait cant find element that exists

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Hello I'm a little new to selenium I'm trying to automate a page for work. The issue I'm having is that webdriver waits are not finding my elements, but I can use those elements if I comment out the wait portion. The issue seems to start after I switch the frame. Is there any additional steps I need to do after that?

Update: When I am debugging and stepping through it works fine. But never works in test run

```cs
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));  
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.CssSelector("iframe[src='/CreditAdmin/']")));   
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("input[aria-label='Filter for column']"))); //This never finds the Element

IWebElement companySearch = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[aria-label='Filter for column']"));  //This works fine if I comment out previous
companySearch.SendKeys(fieldValue);
```

Comment: please include the html source

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("input[aria-label='Filter for column']")));
```

to:

```
wait.Until(c => c.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[aria-label='Filter for column']")));
```

Comment: still same issue :(